Create NSX-T subnet using Ansible
Having an issue creating a subnet in a VmWare NSX-T segment.
Following this code at
https://github.com/simplygeekuk/Ansible-NSXT/blob/master/roles/nsxt_create_ip_pools/tasks/create_ip_pool.yml
seems we can create an ippool with subnets but not the subnets alone.
Is there a way to modify this code to only create the subnets without the ippool?
Perhaps when running the code below the ippool will not be created as it already exits?
- name: "Creating IP Pool: {{ ippool.display_name }}"
 nsxt_ip_pools:
   hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}.{{ dns_default_domain }}"
   username: "{{ nsxt_admin_username }}"
   password: "{{ nsxt_admin_password }}"
   validate_certs: "{{ nsxt_validate_certs }}"
   display_name: "{{ ippool.display_name }}"
   subnets: "{{ ippool.subnets }}"
   state: present```


This code will create the subnet without the ippool. There is no place to specify the vnet so testing will be necessary to figure where exactly the subnet will be created unless there is a default ippool where the new subnet will go.                                                                     ```
- name: Creating Subnet
    nsxt_ip_pools:
    hostname: "{{ inv_hostname }}.{{ dns_default_domain }}"
    username: "{{ nsxt_admin_username }}"
    password: "{{ nsxt_admin_password }}"
    validate_certs: "{{ nsxt_validate_certs }}"
    display_name: "Your Subnet Name"
    subnets: "192.168.11.0/24"  # Specify your desired subnet CIDR here
    state: present


